# ArcGIS Pro Geoprocessing tools do not create output due to file locking issues

Tags: arcgis-pro, geoprocessing

When geoprocessing tools are run in ArcGIS Pro, sometimes I receive errors related to file access issues.  Typically it is errors 229, 210 or 160385.  It says it cannot open the file geodatabase, cannot create output or that the workspace is read only.  I am trying to create output on my laptop in the default file geodatabases that are created upon project creation in My Documents folder.

ArcGIS Pro 2.9 was installed about 10 days ago.  I upgraded to the 2.9.2 patch and I still have the issues.  I have re-installed the software and deleted my profile ESRI folder.  The errors apply to various types of tools including Copy Features, Generate Tessellation, or Select.

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise and ArcGIS Pro version 2.9.2.  Laptop has 32 gigs RAM.

Comment: Does it work if you read/write to a file geodatabase elsewhere on your computer, C drive maybe? If so, that might indicate some process is running on your MyDocuments folder causing the lock.

Comment: @Tigerwoulds I created a c:\temp directory and it still fails.  Transfered projects to there and also created a temp.gdb there as well.  Still fails.